# Automatic updates only in a predefined maintenance window

Tags: automatic-updates

I would like to use the automatic wordpress updates feature.

But **I wish that updates can only be done within a predefined time windows.**
In order to avoid an update during a critical use windows of the site.

If you have ideas for that, I'm interested because my research has given nothing...

Thanks in advance for your help;)

Comment: You mean for example 3-6 AM?

Comment: As @Krzysiek Dróżdż asked, are you trying to make sure the updates only run within a specific time window? If that's the case, I would be interested too and will gladly upvote this question; please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the update run only in a specific time windows and/or specific day.